# How to import list of cookies to requests?

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-requests

I have list of dicts with full cookies of such type:

```
<class 'list'>: [{'name': 'c_user', 'value': '100041356816620', 'expires': 'Sun, 06 Sep 2020 20:12:51 GMT', 'expires_timestamp': 1599423171, 'domain': '.facebook.com', 'path': '/', 'secure': True}, {'name': 'xs', 'value': '40:KIuQ_QG_K0JALw:2:1567887172:-1:-1', 'expires': 'Sun, 06 Sep 2020 20:12:51 GMT', 'expires_timestamp': 1599423171, 'domain': '.facebook.com', 'path': '/', 'secure': True, 'httponly': True}, {'name': 'fr', 'value': '5N1aV12Rlv9dmM9f7.AWVvFfCaNn4mFDxKf5WU3HVX3Fg.BddA9D..AAA.0.0.BddA9D.AWW5fJZ-', 'expires': 'Sun, 06 Sep 2020 20:12:48 GMT', 'expires_timestamp': 1599423168, 'domain': '.facebook.com', 'path': '/', 'secure': True, 'httponly': True}, {'name': 'datr', 'value': 'Qw90X2hNUueymhbnR9mUeYd_', 'expires': 'Mon, 06 Sep 2021 20:12:51 GMT', 'expires_timestamp': 1630959171, 'domain': '.facebook.com', 'path': '/', 'secure': True, 'httponly': True}]
```

How is it possible to load them to requests?
I tried smth like this:

```
cookies = {key: morsel.value for key, morsel in session_cookies}
requests.cookies = cookies
```

But received error

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can easily do so by using the following code:

```
requests.cookies.update(cookies)
```

hope this helps!